# c# HttpWebRequest dont get the response when request is long

Tags: c#, request, httpwebrequest

I am having a problem with the class `HttpWebRequest`.
I'm doing a request in a web server (apache/php) that's execute a script.

The problem is: when the request take more than 10 minutes (it is a big process), my C# program don't get the answer, but when i reduce the loop (in server) C# obtain the answer.

I did the following test in the server side:

```
sleep(10); // 10 seconds
echo "OK";
// In this test everything is ok
```

But when i do this:

```
sleep(900) // 15 minutes of wait
echo "OK";
// C# don't get the "ok", even after 20 minutes
```

My C# class:

```
public class WebBrowser {

private CookieContainer Cookie;
private HttpWebRequest Request;
private string bufferResponse;

public WebBrowser() {
    Cookie = new CookieContainer();
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
}

public CookieContainer GetCookie() {
    return Cookie;
}

public string Get( string url ) {
    return ExecuteGet( url );
}

protected string ExecuteGet( string url ) {
    Request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create( url );
    Request.Method = "get";
    Request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    Request.CookieContainer = Cookie;
    Request.KeepAlive = false;
    Request.ContentLength = 0;
    Request.Timeout = 20 * ( 1000 * 60 ); // minutos
    Request.ReadWriteTimeout = 20 * ( 1000 * 60 ); // minutos
    Request.Proxy = null;
    Request.ServicePoint.SetTcpKeepAlive( true, 30000, 5000 ); //after 30 seconds, each 5 second

    HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse) Request.GetResponse();
    Stream ResponseStream = Response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader ResponseReader = new StreamReader( ResponseStream );

    bufferResponse = ResponseReader.ReadToEnd();

    Response.Close();
    ResponseStream.Close();
    ResponseReader.Close();

    return ( bufferResponse );
}

public string Response() {
    return bufferResponse;
}
```

}

Can someone help me with this, I'm going crazy.

PS: Sorry about the bad english, I'm brazilian.